# Django and Oracle nested table support

Tags: django, oracle, nested

Can Django support Oracle nested tables or varrays or collections in some manner?  Asking just for completeness as our project is reworking the data model, attempting to move away from EAV organization, but I don't like creating a bucket load of dependent supporting tables for each main entity.

e.g.
(not the proper Oracle syntax, but gets the idea across)

Events
  eventid
  report_id
  result_tuple (result_type_id, result_value)
  anomaly_tuple(anomaly_type_id, anomaly_value)
  contributing_factors_tuple(cf_type_id, cf_value)
  etc,

where the can be multiple rows of the tuples for one eventid

each of these tuples can, of course exist as separate tables, but this seems to be more concise.  If it 's something Django can't do, or I can't modify the model classes to do easily, then perhaps just having django create the extra tables is the way to go.

--edit--

I note that [django-hstore](https://github.com/jordanm/django-hstore) is doing something very similar to what I want to do, but using postgresql's hstore capability.  Maybe I can branch off of that for an Oracle nested table implementation.  I dunno...I'm pretty new to python and django, so my reach may exceed my grasp in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Querying a nested table gives you a cursor to traverse the tuples, one member of which is yet another cursor, so you can get the rows from the nested table.